# Cannot call value of non-function type UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I converted my project to Swift 3 and got an error: Cannot call value of non-function type UITextField

in the following line:

```
let url:URL = URL(string: _url!)!
```

full code

```
func StartDownloadingPL(_ urlFromTextField: String?) -> Void {
    let _url = urlFromTextField
    // some url checks...

    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let url:URL = URL(string: _url!)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("download error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        self.ParsePlaylist(dataString)

    }) 

    task.resume()
}
```

URL I am getting from UITextField:

```
@IBAction func DownloadAndParsePL1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    StartDownloadingPL(Playlist1URL.text)
}
```

also

```
@IBOutlet weak var Playlist1URL: UITextField!
```

Comment: The code on itself looks ok, have you checked if everything looks ok at earlier stages? You did try cleaning project, right?

Comment: Where is the error shown? Please also show `Playlist1URL`.

Comment: I tried to clean. Also added outlet code.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a problem, after converting NSURL to URL it has conflict with outlet called URL.